# Jquery - Stacking hidden divs on top of eachother when clicked

Tags: jquery, html, hidden, slidedown

So what I would like to happen when the tabs are clicked on the hidden divs slide down but no matter which one is clicked it will always open on top of the previous. Right now they open in the order they're in, in the HTML. Here is the Jquery `

$(document).ready(function ($) {

```
$('.menu-bio').bind('click', function (event) {
    if ($('#bio').is(':visible')) {
        $('#bio').slideUp();
        $('.menu-bio').removeClass('open');
    } else {
        if ($('#media').is(':visible')) {
            $('#media').slideDown(function () {
                $('#bio').slideDown();
                if($('.dropmenu').first().attr('id') != 'bio') $('#bio').insertBefore($('.dropmenu')[0]);           
            });
        } 
        if ($('#dates').is(':visible')) {
            $('#dates').slideDown(function () {
                $('#bio').slideDown();
                if($('.dropmenu').first().attr('id') != 'bio') $('#bio').insertBefore($('.dropmenu')[0]);           
            });
        } 
        if ($('#contacts').is(':visible')) {
            $('#contacts').slideDown(function () {
                $('#bio').slideDown();
                if($('.dropmenu').first().attr('id') != 'bio') $('#bio').insertBefore($('.dropmenu')[0]);           
            });
        } 
        else {
            $('#bio').slideDown();
        }

        $('.menu-bio').addClass('open');
    }
    return false;
});

$('.menu-media').bind('click', function (event) {
    if ($('#media').is(':visible')) {
        $('#media').slideUp();
        $('.menu-media').removeClass('open');
    } else {
        if ($('#bio').is(':visible')) {
            $('#bio').slideDown(function () {
                $('#media').slideDown();
                if($('.dropmenu').first().attr('id') != 'media') $('#media').insertBefore($('.dropmenu')[0]);
            });
        } 
        if ($('#dates').is(':visible')) {
            $('#dates').slideDown(function () {
                $('#media').slideDown();
                if($('.dropmenu').first().attr('id') != 'media') $('#media').insertBefore($('.dropmenu')[0]);           
            });
        } 
        if ($('#contacts').is(':visible')) {
            $('#contacts').slideDown(function () {
                $('#media').slideDown();
                if($('.dropmenu').first().attr('id') != 'media') $('#media').insertBefore($('.dropmenu')[0]);           
            });
        } 
        else {
            $('#media').slideDown();
        }
        $('.menu-media').addClass('open');
    }
    return false;
});

$('.menu-dates').bind('click', function (event) {
    if ($('#dates').is(':visible')) {
        $('#dates').slideUp();
        $('.menu-dates').removeClass('open');
    } else {
        if ($('#bio').is(':visible')) {
            $('#bio').slideDown(function () {
                $('#dates').slideDown();
                if($('.dropmenu').first().attr('id') != 'dates') $('#dates').insertBefore($('.dropmenu')[0]);

            });
        } 
        if ($('#media').is(':visible')) {
            $('#media').slideDown(function () {
                $('#dates').slideDown();
                if($('.dropmenu').first().attr('id') != 'dates') $('#dates').insertBefore($('.dropmenu')[0]);           
            });
        } 
        if ($('#contacts').is(':visible')) {
            $('#contacts').slideDown(function () {
                $('#dates').slideDown();
                if($('.dropmenu').first().attr('id') != 'dates') $('#dates').insertBefore($('.dropmenu')[0]);           
            });
        } 
        else {
            $('#dates').slideDown();
        }
        $('.menu-dates').addClass('open');
    }
    return false;
});

$('.menu-contacts').bind('click', function (event) {
    if ($('#contacts').is(':visible')) {
        $('#contacts').slideUp();
        $('.menu-contacts').removeClass('open');
    } else {
        if ($('#media').is(':visible')) {
            $('#media').slideDown(function () {
                $('#contacts').slideDown();
                if($('.dropmenu').first().attr('id') != 'contacts') $('#contacts').insertBefore($('.dropmenu')[0]);

            });
        } 
        if ($('#dates').is(':visible')) {
            $('#dates').slideDown(function () {
                $('#contacts').slideDown();
                if($('.dropmenu').first().attr('id') != 'contacts') $('#contacts').insertBefore($('.dropmenu')[0]);         
            });
        } 
        if ($('#bio').is(':visible')) {
            $('#bio').slideDown(function () {
                $('#contacts').slideDown();
                if($('.dropmenu').first().attr('id') != 'contacts') $('#contacts').insertBefore($('.dropmenu')[0]);         
            });
        } 
        else {
            $('#contacts').slideDown();
        }
        $('.menu-contacts').addClass('open');
    }
    return false;
});


$('.openbox').bind('click', function (event) {
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('open')) {
        $(this).next('ul').slidedDown('fast');
        $(this).parent().removeClass('open');
    } else {
        $(this).next('ul').slideUp('fast');
        $(this).parent().addClass('open');
    }
    return false;
});
});
```

If anyone can help me it would be greatly appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Without seeing the HTML, all I can suggest is that you use jQuery to change the z-index of each tab: `$(selector).css("z-index",somenumber);` -- elements will be layered so that larger z-index values lie on top of smaller ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This lines of code do the trick of inserting the element you define `#bio`, `#media` or `#dates` before the other elements. Just have to edit the line below.

```
$('#bio').insertBefore($('.dropmenu')[0]);
$('#media').insertBefore($('.dropmenu')[0]);
$('#dates').insertBefore($('.dropmenu')[0]);
```

Comment: Hmmm. Not sure I understand where these would do so would it look like this 
 `$('.menu-bio').bind('click', function (event) {
  if ($('#bio').is(':visible')) {
   $('#bio').slideUp();
   $('.menu-bio').removeClass('open');
  } else {
   if ($('#media').is(':visible')) {
    $('#media').slideDown(function () {
     $('#bio').slideDown();
     $('#media').insertBefore($('#dates')[0]);
     $('#dates').insertBefore($('#bio')[0]);    
    });
   } else {
    $('#bio').slideDown();
   }
   $('.menu-bio').addClass('open');
  }
  return false;
 });`

Comment: Ok I implemented the code you gave me and it works fine for media but when I try and do it to the others it starts working really weird. Here is it just under the media tab  http://ericlanglay.com/Jermaine/index.php

Comment: you only change the first part, not the `$('.dropmenu')[0]`. `$('#<change-this>').insertBefore($('.dropmenu')[0]);`

Comment: Yah I found that out pretty quick, haha. I changed the jquery (and reposted it in the original question up there) if you want to see what it looks like check out the link again. It still doesn't seem to be working right. Not really sure why. Thanks, you've been a big help so far

Comment: I think that if the div is already the first one, instead of inserting  on top, it deletes. So try: `if($('.dropmenu').first().attr('id') != 'media') $('#media').insertBefore($('.dropmenu')[0]);` changing both media to the proper id.

Comment: Hey so I changed that all and it's working better but...it's weird. Sometimes things will properly work then they'll suddenly not work. Or if i keep randomizing what link I'm clicking on it will drop underneath instead of on top. I changed the code to what it is now up top. Any thoughts?

Comment: It's like certain combinations of the links I press throw it off. I wonder if it as something to do with this snippet of code               else {
        if ($('#media').is(':visible')) {
            $('#media').slideDown(function () {
                $('#bio').slideDown();
                if($('.dropmenu').first().attr('#media') != 'bio') $('#bio').insertBefore($('.dropmenu')[0]);           
            });
        }

Comment: YES! figured it out...I just needed some more conditions for each div. I put the finished code up there. THANKS AGAIN!

Answer (score 0):

Use [insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) to insert the container after the wrapper before slide down:

```
$('#bio').insertAfter('.wrapper').slideDown();
```